# Ignoring a line on Comparing two strings

Tags: c#, string

I need to compare two strings representing an html (something like 300 lines both). They should be identical, except a line which contains a date in this format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, so I need to ignore that line.

The problem is that I have a static file containing one html which I use as the base in comparing, and the other one I get on  runtime from a `URL`. So this line with that date will be always different.

The line doesn't have any identifier tag, like `id` or `name`, even the parent elements doesn't have nothing to identify it. So, what options do I have to ignore this line in the comparing method?

Comment: what do you want to be the result of the comparison? `yes / no they're the same`? or do you want to see the differences?

Comment: i do not want to see the differences, just if they are different

Comment: Do a line-by-line comparison. If off by one line, then check to see if that line is the known offender - then do as you please?

Comment: Remove the discrepancies using regex replace and then compare, my ans below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the date time with a Regex.Replace, then compare the strings.

Comment: If there is 2 dates in string 1 and 3 dates in string 2, it won't work.

Comment: all dates will be removed and so it will work, assuming the rest of the document is the same.

Comment: Let's assume that s1=dateA +xxx+CRLF+dateB and s2=DateC+xxx+CRLF+DateD. There one difference (e.g. dateA!=dateC) that should be ignored and a second one (e.g. dateB!=dateD) that matters.

Comment: with regex replace you would remove all dates given their format, not their content, so dateA to dateD will be removed leaving s1=xxx+CRLF and s2=xxx+CRLF

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find wich is the position in the string of the sequence of chars that define the date line.

Suppose your date line starts with  "mydate".

Get the first part of the string from index 0 to indexOf("mydate") from the two files and compare them (if you do not find "mydate", then something is really different, the date line was not found).

Then get the second part of the string from the index of what should be directly after the date line from the two files and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can **remove both datetimes** from both htmls **using regex**, **then compare** them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution consist in identifying the characters of static HTML (s1) that are not identical to the HTML (S2) got from URL.

*A prerequisite is to update the static HTML s1 by replacing the DateTime by a string like "##.##.##.##.##.##" insuring that all characters of this string cannot match any char (including separators) of the DateTime in s2.*

```
string originalDateTimeString = "##.##.##.##.##.##" ; 

// check to see if same length
bool compareok=s1.Length==s2.Length ;
// check all char. when different store char in diff1
string diff1="" ;
int lastDiffIndex =-1 ;
for (int i=0;i<s1.Length && compareok; i ++) if(s1[i]!=s2[i])
{ // Check if differences are consecutive
  compareok = lastDiffIndex==-1 || lastDiffIndex==i-1 ; 
  diff1+=s1[i] ; 
  lastDiffIndex=i ; 
}

// The comparison succeeds if the differences matches the original DateTime string  
compareok = compareok && diff1==originalDateTimeString ;
```